# Cannot get each drive to report and each cert to report when running this script

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

So, this script outputs MOST of the information that I need.

However,

1. it doesn't report or post all the drives that are on each server, or all of the certificates listed.
2. The builddate comes out as 20210218123012.000000-300 instead of standard mm/dd/yyyy
3. And the drive space comes out as 39.8967208862305 instead of a %

These should all be grouped together with each of the server names.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Select the servers you want to hit $server = (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=OU" -filter *).name

$scriptblock = {
    # Set the server name
    $serverName = $env:computername
    # Get the up/down status of the server
    $pingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Count 1
    $status = if ($pingResult.StatusCode -eq 0) {
        'Up'
    }
    else {
        'Down'
    }
    # Get the server build date
    $os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
    $buildDate = $os.InstallDate
    # Get the server certificate validity
    $cert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My |
        Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } |
        Sort-Object -Property NotBefore |
        Select-Object -First 1
    $validFrom = $cert.NotBefore
    $validTo = $cert.NotAfter
    #Check Trellix update
    $TrellixDate = [datetime](get-itemproperty "C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\Engine\AMCoreUpdater\amupdate.dat").lastwritetime.DateTime

    foreach ($disk in (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $env:computername -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType = 3')) {
        $diskLabel = $disk.DeviceID
        $freeSpace = $disk.FreeSpace / 1GB
        $diskSize = $disk.Size / 1GB
        $percent = $freeSpace / $diskSize * 100
    }
    # Create a custom object with the collected information
    $serverInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
        ServerName           = $serverName
        Status               = $status
        BuildDate            = $buildDate.datetime
        CertificateValidFrom = $validFrom
        CertificateValidTo   = $validTo
        TrellixLastUpdate    = $TrellixDate
        DiskLabel            = $diskLabel
        Freespace            = $freespace
        DiskSize             = $disksize
        Percent              = $percent
    }
    # Export the information to a CSV file
    $serverInfo | Export-Csv -Path '\nec\ServerInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation
}
Write-Host 'Server information exported to ServerInfo.csv'
#command to run the script on the servers
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $scriptblock
}

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $CSV = Get-ChildItem -Filter ServerInfo.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Import-Csv
}

Export-Csv c:\NEC\CombinedFile.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: The best export format for this would be Json instead of Csv otherwise you will need to create one object per certificate and per disk

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to pull all of these into a csv file so that eventually I can important it into excel eventually. If there is a way to do this otherwise, that would be great.

Comment: The certificate issue being limited to 1 is due to `Select-Object -First 1` but again, if you want to pull all certificates, you need to define how the output should look. What happens if you have 20 certs and 3 Disks in one server, how should the output look? Thats why Json sounds like the correct output for this, a single object with some properties that are objects within themselves like for disks and certs.

Comment: I am unsure how to create, define or do a json file. I am still very new to everything powershell. I cannot seem to get the right variable to show names of the certs or multiple ones. If I wanted to call up the list of certs, how would i get them? Sorry if I am making things difficult.

Comment: You could export an output like this: https://i.imgur.com/juhexvV.png this would be a single row per computer in your Csv but the properties `DisksInfo` and `CertsInfo` are represented as a table. Does this work for you?

Comment: https://imgur.com/MEHUlZL This is kinda what I am trying to get to happen here. Hopefully this helps a little bit?

Comment: you're showing 1 disk and 1 cert per row per computer there while repeating the other data like build date ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256279/discussion-between-bobsnarley-and-santiago-squarzon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. It doesn't report or post all the drives that are on each server, or all of the certificates listed.

This happens because you're creating a single `pscustomobject` no matter how many certs or how disks, what you need to do is enumerate both (certs and disks) and create 1 object per each. This is demonstrated with the `for` loop in the following code.

> 2. The `.BuildDate` comes out as `20210218123012.000000-300` instead of standard `mm/dd/yyyy`.

This is the default format for this property when using `Get-WmiObject` targeting the `OperatingSystem` class. In this case the recommendation is to **not use this cmdlet** mainly because it no longer exists in newer version of PowerShell, it is essentially obsolete. Use `Get-CimInstance` instead, the syntax is for the most part the same and the type of this property will be `DateTime` which can be easily transformed into a string in your desired format, a few examples:

```bash
# using the `u` format specifier (Outputs: 2021-02-04 12:19:19Z)
'{0:u}' -f (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate
# using the `s` format specifier (Outputs: 2021-02-04T12:19:19)
'{0:s}' -f (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate
# using a custom `MM/dd/yyyy` format specifier (Outputs: 02/04/2021)
'{0:MM/dd/yyyy}' -f (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate
```

See also [Table of format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#table-of-format-specifiers) for reference.

> 3. And the drive space comes out as `39.8967208862305` instead of a `%`.

For this you can change `$freeSpace / $diskSize * 100` to just `$freeSpace / $diskSize` and use the `P` (*Percent*) Format specifier, for example:

```bash
# lets assume you have 20Gb free space out of 1Tb
'{0:P}' -f (20Gb / 1Tb) # Outputs: 1.95%
```

See also [Standard format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#standard-format-specifiers) for reference.

Finally, how the code should look in the end, **unless there is a specific need to store the CSVs in each server and then pull that info from them** I don't see why you couldn't just capture the output from `Invoke-Command` directly, without needing merge the outputs from each server, this makes things much simpler. Because of this, I have removed `Export-Csv` statement from inside the `$scriptblock`.

Also worth noting, `Invoke-Command` can perform parallel invocation without the need of a `foreach` loop, simply pass in the `$servers` array directly to the cmdlet.

```bash
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Select the servers you want to hit $server = (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=OU" -filter *).name

$scriptblock = {
    # Set the server name
    $serverName = $env:computername

    # Get the up/down status of the server
    $pingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Count 1
    $status = if ($pingResult.StatusCode -eq 0) {
        'Up'
    }
    else {
        'Down'
    }

    # Get the server build date
    $buildDate = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate

    # Get the server certificate validity
    [array] $certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My |
        Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
        Sort-Object -Property NotBefore

    #Check Trellix update
    $TrellixDate = [datetime](Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\Engine\AMCoreUpdater\amupdate.dat').LastWriteTime.DateTime

    [array] $diskInfo = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType = 3'

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt [System.Math]::Max($cert.Count, $diskInfo.Count); $i++) {
        $freeSpace = $diskSize = $percent = $label = $validTo = $validFrom = $null
        $disk = $diskInfo[$i]
        $cert = $certs[$i]

        if ($disk) {
            $label = $disk.DeviceID
            $freeSpace = $disk.FreeSpace / 1GB
            $diskSize = $disk.Size / 1GB
            $percent = '{0:P0}' -f ($freeSpace / $diskSize)
        }

        if ($cert) {
            $validTo = $cert.NotAfter
            $validFrom = $cert.NotBefore
        }

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ServerName           = $serverName
            Status               = $status
            BuildDate            = '{0:u}' -f $buildDate
            CertificateValidFrom = $validFrom
            CertificateValidTo   = $validTo
            TrellixLastUpdate    = $TrellixDate
            DiskLabel            = $label
            Freespace            = '{0:N2} Gb' -f $freespace
            DiskSize             = '{0:N2} Gb' -f $disksize
            Percent              = $percent
        }
    }
}

#command to run the script on the servers
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -HideComputerName |
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId |
    Export-Csv c:\NEC\CombinedFile.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

A sample of the final output should be something like:

[image: sample]

Comment: @BobSnarley if they're reporting twice is because they have more than 1 disk or more than 1 certificate.

Comment: no... I am just an idiot. I forgot about the -Append. Removed my idiot question.

Comment: Its writing PSComputerName and PSShowComputerName but, I am not reading where that is calling it to print to the csv.

Comment: @BobSnarley those 2 properties are automatically added to the objects when using `Invoke-Command` against remote computers. You could change the `Select-Object` line to `Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId, PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName` to exclude them